# Stubbing with sinon in jest

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs, sinon

I have all my unit tests in jests.

Keen to use sinon stubs for some tests. Can sinon be used with jest as test runner? Couldn't find much on the internet about combining these two

The problem I am trying solve is similar to the below code

```
const Meme = require('./Meme');

module.exports.allMemes = function(req, res) {
    Meme.find({ repost: req.params.reposts }, function(err, memes) {
        res.send(memes);
    });
};
```

where `Meme` is a `mongoose Schema` and I would like to stub the `Meme.find()`  function so that I don't have to deal with the problematic part of mongoDB return

Any guidance?

Comment: Yes you can use the two together.  Personally I prefer to just use Jest mocks and stubs.  One less dependency to manage and I have never seen anything that Sinon does that jest doesn't.

Comment: yes, sinon works great with jest and tends to be a bit more refined in areas such as [testing calls to spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/) and [fake timers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/)

Comment: Yes. I am specially keen on sinon capacity to deal with spies. I am relatively new to unit testing. Do you have any pointers to online resources or any snippets where both sinon and jest are used at the same time. I am hoping the expect() method will be from jest and everything else will be related to sinon

Comment: Please, can you provide an example you like to use spices in?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I have edited the question :-)